# i18n error: controller and templates uses different implicit languages

Tags: templates, internationalization, controller, playframework-2.0

Controller:

```
def test = Action { implicit request =>
    import play.api.i18n._
    val msg = Messages("error.invalid")
    implicit val langInController = lang(request)
    Ok(views.html.test(langInController, msg))
}
```

View:

```
@(langInController: play.api.i18n.Lang, msg:String)(implicit request: Request[_])
<div>Lang from controller: @langInController, Message: @msg</div>
<div>Message from view: @play.api.i18n.Messages("error.required")</div>
```

Messages resource, `conf/messages.zh-CN`:

```
error.required=该字段必填
```

**Trying**

1. Uses an English Firefox which sends the request header `Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5` to visit the `test` action. The result is:

   ```
   Language from controller: Lang(en,), Message: This field is required
   Message in view: 该字段必填
   ```
2. Uses an Chinese Google Chrome which sends the request header `Accept-Language:zh-CN,zh;q=0.8` to visit it. The result is:

   ```
   Language: Lang(zh,CN), Message: 该字段必填
   Message in view: 该字段必填
   ```

From the tests, we know that:

1. The implicit language in the controller is from the request header's `Accept-Language`
2. The implicit language used in template is determined by the OS

Environment:

1. Play 2 is latest play2.1-SNAPSHOT from GitHub (2012-03-16)
2. My OS is Windows 7 x64 Chinese version

I think Play 2 should use the same implicit language for controllers and views. I can fix it by adding something in `Build.sbt`:

```
val main = PlayProject(...) (
    templatesImport ++= Seq("utilis.TemplateMixin._")
)
```

Where the `TemplateMixin` is just:

```
object TemplateMixin extends play.api.mvc.Controller
```

(It extends Controller and is just to reuse some methods, like `implicit def lang(request)`.)

But I think it should be done by the Play framework.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `play.api.i18n.Messages(key)` function takes an additional implicit parameter of type `Lang`. So when you write `Messages("foo")` it is expanded to `Messages("foo")(l)`, where `l` is a value of type `Lang` taken from the current implicit scope.

There’s always an available [default implicit lang](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/play/api/i18n/Lang$.html#defaultLang:Lang) (which has a [low priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886953/is-there-a-way-to-control-which-implicit-conversion-will-be-the-default-used)), using your jvm default locale.

But when you are inside a [Controller](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/play/api/mvc/Controller.html#lang(RequestHeader):Lang), an implicit value with a higher priority can be found if there is an implicit request. This value looks in the `Accept-Language` header of the request.

When you are inside a template, the default implicit lang will be used unless your template imports another implicit lang.

That’s why, in your example, messages computed from the Controller use the `Accept-Language` request header and messages computed from the View use your jvm default locale.

If you add an implicit parameter of type `Lang` to your template, this parameter will have a higher priority than the default lang and will be used to compute messages:

```html
@(langInController: Lang, msg:String)(implicit request: RequestHeader, lang: Lang)

<div>Lang from controller: @langInController, Message: @msg</div>
<div>Message from view: @Messages("error.required")</div>
```

When you’ll call the template from a Controller action, its implicit lang will be passed, so the same lang will be used by both your Views and your Controllers.

Comment: Thanks again. A good answer should be added to the play2's documents.

Comment: Why can't this be the default behavior? I would imagine most apps would want the implicit Land in the view to be the same one used in the controller.

Comment: Making this the default behavior would require to differentiate between templates intended to be used with Java controllers (which can’t provide implicit values) and templates intended to be used with Scala controllers.