# Play framework : Setting Lang in a helper.form in a scala view

Tags: internationalization, playframework-2.0

I've got the following code in a view :

```
@(lang:Lang)...
...
<div>
...
@helper.form(action = routes.item.add) {
     <p>@helper.inputText(myItem("name"))</p>
     ...
    }
...
</div>
```

In my internationalization files, i have entries for `name`.
e.g. :

- in `messages.en` : `name=Name`
- in `messages.fr` : `name=Nom`

The view is always rendered with the french label for this `inputText` and I don't know how to change for another langage, e.g. using the global parameter `lang` defined in my view.

I was looking for some solutions like : `@helper.form(action = routes.item.add, lang)` or the same kind of code at `inputText` level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution :

```
@(lang:Lang)...

@import play.i18n._

@translate(text: String) = @{
 Message.get(lang, text)
}
...
<div>
...
@helper.form(action = routes.item.add) {
     <p>@helper.inputText(myItem("name"), '_label -> translate("name"))</p>
     ...
    }
...
</div>
```

In Play, it's possible to add attribute to the forms with the `'_` convention. I have overriden the label using this by applying my own translate function.

Comment: Why do you pass the lang as a String?

Comment: Good question : I think it's useless to pass the lang because I've got it in my cookie. I will have a look later and update my answer. Thanks for the idea. But maybe you have another option in mind?

Comment: Are you using Scala or Java? I'd pass lang as `Lang` directly.

Comment: I use Java. Following your comment, i update question and answer, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `Scala` or `Java`? With Scala you can set a implicit language. But for Java this is not easy as in Play 1.2.4:

```
Lang.set(...) or .change()
```

This will be solved in 2.1: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/174-20-i18n-add-ability-to-define-implicit-lang-for-java-api

See previous discussion in Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/dE1SPBaTM6w

Is you use scala have a look at post: [i18n error: controller and templates uses different implicit languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733082/i18n-error-controller-and-templates-uses-different-implicit-langs?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the good links ! I found a solution derived from those. I'll post this solution for information.