# Scala play internationalization: how to set an explicit language across all templates

Tags: scala, internationalization, playframework-2.0

I've read through the documentation: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaI18N
and this post:
[i18n error: controller and templates uses different implicit languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733082/i18n-error-controller-and-templates-uses-different-implicit-languages?answertab=active#tab-top)
and it looks straightforward to set the language implicitly from the request header if there is an implicit request. In my application I need to set the language across all templates according to a certain logic (that doesn't depend on the language in the request header). Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to add an extra implicit argument in your view like this:

```
@(form:Form[_])(implicit lang:play.api.i18n.Lang)
```

Then in your controller you add a line like this:

```
// this retrieves the language from the configuration, 
// replace it with your own logic
implicit val defaultLang = Lang.availables.headOption.getOrElse(Lang.defaultLang)
```

Comment: You could leave out the form and just do this: `@()(implicit lang:play.api.i18n.Lang)`, the form was just an example