# How to control priority of implicit conversions applied on method arguments?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, overloading

Assume code:

```
class A
class B

class Something {
  def method(arg: A) = ???
  def method(arg: B) = ???
}

class C

object C {
  implicit def ctoa(c: C): A = ???
  implicit def ctob(c: C): B = ???
}
```

Additionally:

- Classes `A`, `B` and `Something` and their companions cannot be modified
- There must be an implicit conversion from `C` to `A` and from `C` to `B`, their priority doesn't matter
- Other than that, class `C` and its companion can be freely modified
- Of course, more types, implicits etc. can be added

Now, is there a way to make this compile:

```
(new Something).method(new C)
```

?

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't what you were looking for, but I don't see any way to do it except to get one of those implicits into another scope.

```
class A
class B

class Something {
  def method(arg: A) = println("method(A)")
  def method(arg: B) = println("method(B)")
}

class C

object C {
  implicit def ctoa(c: C): A = new A
}

object X {
  implicit def ctob(c: C): B = new B
}
```

Then you get:

```
scala> (new Something).method(new C)
method(A)
```

Otherwise, you're trying to violate the Non-Ambiguity Rule: "An implicit conversion is only inserted if there is no other possible conversion to insert."  See [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html).

Comment: There is a way to control priority of implicit conversions in case of ambiguity (e.g. by putting low priority implicits into a superclass/trait) but I don't know why it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: What's your source for that superclass/trait thing?

Daniel Sobral did a post about implicit priorities. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits

C.ctoa and C.ctob are in the same compilation unit, so I think the precedence groups described by Daniel don't come into play.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886953/is-there-a-way-to-control-which-implicit-conversion-will-be-the-default-used