# How to avoid ambiguous conversion chains with multiple Type Class relationships?

Tags: scala, typeclass, context-bound

In my library, I have three type classes:

```
trait Monoid[T] {
  val zero : T
  def sum(x : T, y : T) : T
}

trait AbelianGroup[T] extends Monoid[T] {
  def inverse(x : T) : T
  def difference(x : T, y : T) : T
}

//represents types that are represents lists with a fixed number of elements, such as
//the tuple type (Int, Int)
trait Vector[T, U] {
  ...
}
```

These type classes are convertible to one another under the following conditions:

- If type `T` is a `scala.math.Numeric` type, it is also an `AbelianGroup`.
- If type `T` is an `AbelianGroup`, it is also a `Monoid` (currently, `AbelianGroup` extends `Monoid`, but that need not necessarily be the case)
- If type `T` is a Vector over type U, and type U is a `Monoid`, then type `T` is also a `Monoid`.
- If type T is a Vector over type U, and type U is a `AbelianGroup`, then `T` is also an `AbelianGroup`.

For example, since `(Int, Int)` is a Vector over type `Int`, and `Int` is an AbelianGroup, then `(Int, Int)` is also an AbelianGroup.

These relationships and others are easily implemented in the companion classes like so:

```
object Monoid {
  implicit def fromAbelianGroup[T : AbelianGroup] : Monoid[T] = implicitly[AbelianGroup[T]]
  implicit def fromVector[T : Vector[T, U], U : Monoid] : Monid[T] = ...
}

object AbelianGroup {
  implicit def fromNumeric[T : Numeric] : AbelianGroup[T] = ...
  implicit def fromOtherTypeX[T : ...] : AbelianGroup[T]
  ...
  implicit def fromVector[T : Vector[T, U], U : AbelianGroup] : AbelianGroup[T] = ...
}
```

This works out great until you try to use something like the tuple type `(Int, Int)` as a Monoid.  The compiler finds two ways to get a Monoid type class object for such a type:

1. `Monoid.fromAbelianGroup(AbelianGroup.fromVector(Vector.from2Tuple,
   AbelianGroup.fromNumeric))`
2. `Monoid.fromVector(Vector.from2Tuple,
   Monid.fromAbelianGroup(AbelianGroup.fromNumeric))`

To resolve this ambiguity, I modified the Monoid companion class to include a direct conversion from Numeric (and other types directly convertible to `AbelianGroup`).

```
/*revised*/
object Monoid {
  //implicit def fromAbelianGroup[T : AbelianGroup] : Monoid[T] = implicitly[AbelianGroup[T]]
  implicit def fromNumeric[T : Numeric] : Monoid[T] = ... //<-- redundant
  implicit def fromOtherTypeX[T : ...] : AbelianGroup[T] = ... //<-- redundant
  ...
  implicit def fromVector[T : Vector[T, U], U : Monoid] : Monid[T] = ...
}

object AbelianGroup {
  implicit def fromNumeric[T : Numeric] : AbelianGroup[T] = ...
  implicit def fromOtherTypeX[T : ...] : AbelianGroup[T] = ...
  ...
  implicit def fromVector[T : Vector[T, U], U : AbelianGroup] : AbelianGroup[T] = ...
}
```

However, this is a bit unsatisfying, as it essentially violates the DRY principal.  When I add new implementations for `AbelianGroup`s, I would have to implement a conversion in both companion objects, just as I have done for `Numeric` and OtherTypeX, etc.  So, I feel like I've taken a wrong turn somewhere.

Is there a way to revise my code to avoid this redundancy AND resolve the compile-time ambiguity error?  What is the best practice in this kind of scenario?

Comment: Why do you need `fromAbelianGroup`? An `AbelianGroup[T]` already is a `Monoid[T]`, and the compiler will provide one anywhere `Monoid[T]` is required.

Comment: Because the compiler looks for possible conversions in Monoid's companion class, so without fromAbelianGroup, it won't find the conversion fromNumberic, etc.  Also, if I import AbelianGroup's companion object at every call site so that it finds the conversions (something I really don't consider a satisfactory solution), the ambiguity will still exist even without fromAbelianGroup.

Comment: Can you post a gist with the code that doesn't compile (v1) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can [move the implicits for which you want to have lower priority into a supertype of the companion object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1887678/9204):

```
trait LowPriorityMonoidImplicits {
  implicit def fromVector[T : Vector[T, U], U : Monoid] : Monoid[T] = ...
}

object Monoid extends LowPriorityMonoidImplicits  {
  implicit def fromAbelianGroup[T : AbelianGroup] : Monoid[T] = implicitly[AbelianGroup[T]]
}
```